# Is there a CPU that can be described as "Celeron D 4xx model"?

Tags: cpu, compatibility

The "D" letter after Celeron appears to only be used for processors numbered with 3xx. Celerons of the 4xx series do not seem to have the "D".

And yet I am looking at a motherboard described as supporting these processors:

- Intel Celeron D 3xx and 4xx models
- Intel Pentium 4 5xx and 6xx models
- Intel Pentium D 8xx and 9xx models
- Intel Core 2 Duo models with LGA775

Is this compatible with a Celeron 450, sSpec SLAFZ, despite not having a "D" in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes from your question I see the board is compatible with LGA 775 Core 2's which tells me the board is socket LGA775. The [Celeron 450](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=35239&processor=450&spec-codes=SLAFZ) is also socket LGA775 and will be compatible with that board. I'm not sure why they specify D I would suspect that is a typo from the manufacturer you will be fine with the 450 on that board.

Comment: Correct, it's LGA775. Are you drawing your conclusion based solely on the socket type? I get the impression that older 775 motherboards do not support all LGA775 CPUs.

Comment: True @romkyns but they specify 4xxx as being compatible I feel like the D is just a typo since they also specify all D3xx and if you look on the Intel site alot of D3xx series processors aren't LGA 775. Also if they specify "Core 2" it can't be that old of a board.

Comment: @techie007 I get what they are trying to say now...thx

Comment: I decided it was best to just stick it in it's own answer, apparently as you read it. ;)  Either way -- as long as it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two model categories: Intel Celeron "D 3xx" and "4xx" models.

Since there was no "non-D" 3xx's it's a little redundant, but still accurate; theres no such thing as a "D 4xx".

So - all 3xx series Celerons are "D"'s (*not* meaning dual core) from the Penitum 4 era (Prescott), and the 4xx series Celerons are from the "Core" era (Conroe).

Since you didn't specify exactly *which* MB you're looking at, I'll have to go the vague route and say it *should* be compatible since you have a 4xx-series and it says it works with them (and we've established the "D" doesn't really matter).

Hope that helps...